# Where can I find a complete list of Windows STOP error codes?

Tags: windows, bsod, documentation

Its all in the title, really. I need a list of STOP (blue screen) error codes so that when I see one, I can look it up. You'd think this would be documented somewhere, but I'll be darned if I can find it. Anyone got a link?

Answer (score 8):

This site might be of help to you: [Troubleshooting Windows STOP Messages](http://www.aumha.org/a/stop.php)

And an even better site with a lot of information is: [Bug Check Code Reference (Windows Debuggers)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994433(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Not very official documentation, but quite a useful collection of stop codes nonetheless:

[List of Blue Screen Error Codes (STOP Codes)](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/tp/stop_error_list.htm)

Answer (score 0):

James Eschelman stopped updating the STOP codes at Aumha.org in 2007. In 2009 I took up the task of keeping an updated list here:
http://www.carrona.org/bsodindx.html

- Updated through W10 (10240) - 480+ STOP codes

Working page for W10 (10586) at:  http://www.carrona.org/bsodindxNEW.html

- Added another 48ish STOP codes